# How do I tap into Vue-Router Navigation guard?

Tags: vue-router

I have [this code](https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/9954ef7c5f3538857edd2c5cf33bee8f), but when I try to navigate to a different route the event is never called. How do I fire an event when there is a route change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked...

```
watch: {
   '$route' (to, from) {
     console.log('route switched')
   }
}
```